# can not cast ConstantInt in llvm

Tags: llvm

Following code:

```
ConstantInt * Idx = cast<ConstantInt>(gepi->getOperand(2));
```

generates following error:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct llvm::ConstantInt’
error: forward declaration of ‘struct llvm::ConstantInt’
```

I don't know why this cast won't work. I am using llvm 3.1. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `#include <Constants.h>` to your source.